# Can I install Ubuntu Mobile OS in my Samsung Galaxy Grand (android)?

Tags: android, ubuntu-touch, samsung

I want to use Ubuntu in my smart phone, as I was a huge fan of it.
So, is there any possibility to install Ubuntu OS in android mobiles?

Thanks,
sairam

Answer (score 2):

I think it is far too early to be installing Ubuntu Mobile unless you are a developer.

In which case you should probably read up to get enough knowledge to know how to do this yourself and how you would revert it if things go wrong before you start.

I recommend checking out the XDA forum for your phone to see if anyone is currently working on it and to see what the progress is like.